# Iterating through a sub range of a collection with *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Can we iterate through a sub range of a collection using *ngFor?

For example I have a set of check boxes with their form control name and label defined like this:

```
[{id: 'c1', label: 'C1'}, ...]
```

Lets assume the length of the array is 8 and I want to place the first four items in the first grid tile and the items 5-8 in the second grid tile.

Can we iterate items 5-8 only using *ngFor?

Comment: I think you can implement a pipe to slice data from the original array or you can have a method which does that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in `*ngFor`.
Example:

In your component:

```
this.elements = [{id: 'c1', label: 'C1'}, ...];
```

In you html:

```
<div *ngFor="let el of elements.slice(5, 8)"></div>
```

Or using [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) as **Hsuan Lee** mentioned will also give the same result:

```
<div *ngFor="let el of elements | slice:5:8"></div>
```

Comment: In the notes of `SlicePipe` it says "All behavior is based on the expected behavior of the JavaScript API Array.prototype.slice() and String.prototype.slice()." so it's the same here. But still worth to mention. Thank you @HsuanLee.